# how to hide and show text box according to select value using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i want to hide and show my text box according to drop down select value. if user select drop down value "other" then i want show my text box and hide drop down list and he can select any value except other my text box is hide plz help me and give me sample code my code is here

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $( function () {

 if($("#subject").val()==="Other") {
     $("#Sub").show();
  $("#subject").hide();

  }
  else $("#Sub").hide(); 
    });
```

```
  <tr> <td style="width: 470px"><%:Html.DropDownList("subject",ViewData["sub"] as SelectList) %> 

      <input type ="text"  name="subject" id="Sub"style="width: 250px" /></td></tr>
```

i populated drop down list from data base

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you must attach an event on "change" event of the select (and hide the text input first). try this:

```
$("#Sub").hide();
$("#subject").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === "Other"){
        $("#Sub").show(); 
        $("#subject").hide();
    }else{
        $("#Sub").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: try u r code i select second value the my text box also hide without selecting other

Comment: You wanted to hide the selct and show the textbox when you select "other" and hide the textbox when you select any vlue that is not other. that is what i understood. Post your generated html code so that i can help you better

Comment: when i select any value except "other" i want hide my text box when i select the value "other" then i want hide my select box

Comment: Look at the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YjtD9/ if you textbox hides too when you select "other" you might have some different problem. try to show us the generated html

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

       $("#Sub").hide();
       $("#subject").change(function () {
           if ($(this).val() === "Other") {
               $("#Sub").show();
               $("#subject").hide();
           } else {
               $("#Sub").hide();
           }
       });                                                                         <td style="width: 470px"><%:Html.DropDownList("subject", ViewData["sub"] as SelectList)%> 
<input type ="text"  name="subject" id="Sub"style="width: 250px" /></td></tr>here is my code plz help me i check out u r link same i want

Comment: i use asp mvc view i checked out u r link it working fine but where i wrong my code is not working

Comment: Can you pleas post the html that is generated (what you see in the browser, you can find it in the browser option "view source") so that i can tell you what is wrong?Also post the code editicg your question and not here

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  <tr> <td style="width: 470px"><%:Html.DropDownList("subject",ViewData["sub"] as SelectList,new {onchange="ShowHideTextBox()"}) %> 

  <input type ="text"  name="subject" id="Sub" style="width: 250px" /></td></tr>
```

**javascript**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function ShowHideTextBox() {

    if($("#subject").val().toUpperCase()=="OTHER") {
         $("#Sub").show();
         $("#subject").hide();
    }
    else
    {
       $("#Sub").hide(); 
    } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: this code is not working when i select value "other " the text box also hide

Comment: this because I compare with `Other` not `other` so I edited my answer to convert the value of dropdown to upper case and compare it with `OTHER`

Comment: thanks for replay i try it but it is not working i use asp mvc view plz help me

Comment: try to use newer version of jquery [1.6.2](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js)