# access MVC dropdown selected value in the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a DropDownList and a TextArea in a Razor View. I want the TextArea to be visible only if specific value in the drop down has been selected. what solution is there to do that? Here is what I have tried so far but it is not quite right because it assumes the value of Security type is set.

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 200px; height: 30px">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecurityTypeId)
    </td>
    <td style="width: 400px; height: 30px">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SecurityTypeId, Model.SecurityTypes, dropdownHtmlAttrs)
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    @if (Model.SecurityTypeId == (int)(SecurityType.Other))
    {
        <td style="width: 200px; height: 30px">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Details)
        </td>
        <td style="width: 400px; height: 30px">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Details, new { Style = "width:240px" })
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    }
</tr>
```

Comment: You need javascript/jquery if you want to respond to client side events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery when handling visibility of view element(s) on client-side event, with `show` or `hide` method. Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#SecurityTypeId').change(function () {
          var value = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (value == "set") { // this condition may adjusted to certain preset value
              $('#Details').show(); // show text area
          }
          else {
              $('#Details').hide(); // hide text area
          }
     });
});
</script>
```

If you prefer using vanilla JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ddlvalue = document.getElementById("SecurityTypeId").value;
    if (ddlvalue == "set") {
        document.getElementById("Details")).style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("Details")).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>
```

Those scripts above assume id attribute of `DropDownListFor` and `TextAreaFor` are exactly same as the model binding name, depending on your needs.

AFAIK, if statement inside Razor works when a view performing callback or postback, thus only changes visibility after an ajax function or a form submit.

Any suggestions and improvements welcome.

References:

[how to hide and show text box according to select value using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677271/how-to-hide-and-show-text-box-according-to-select-value-using-jquery)

[Show/hide control based on dropdown selection mvc 4 razor c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589969/show-hide-control-based-on-dropdown-selection-mvc-4-razor-c-sharp)